# Error using for loop (objects inside array)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a table with an array (products). My data works however it's currently putting all of the information in one row:

```js
const products = [{
            username: JSON.stringify(data, ['from']),
            content: JSON.stringify(data, ['content']),
            date: JSON.stringify(data, ['updatedAt'])
            }]
```

However, I'm trying to create a for loop to make a new object for every data item. I thought I had the right concept but this isn't working at all:

```js
const products = [
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            username: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['from']),
            content: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['content']),
            date: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['updatedAt'])
            }]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why isn't it just `username: data.from`? Why are you stringifying all the things?

Comment: You are looking for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Andy data.from doesn't return anything, I'm fetching using an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `map`.

```
const products = data.map(item => ({
                username: JSON.stringify(item, ['from']),
                content: JSON.stringify(item, ['content']),
                date: JSON.stringify(item, ['updatedAt'])
               }))
```

or using `for` loop.

```
let products = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                products.push({
                username: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['from']),
                content: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['content']),
                date: JSON.stringify(data[i], ['updatedAt'])
                }) 
            }
```

You can avoid stringify if not needed.

```
const products = data.map(item => ({
                username: item.from,
                content: item.content,
                date: item.updatedAt,
               }))
```

Comment: Hello, Writing this answer on mobile device, Editing help to format the code will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is perfect, thx a lot

Comment: No problem Wesley Bond, if this solves the problem then kindly consider accepting the answer. That'll help to mark this done.

Comment: of course, there's a time limit on how soon you can accept an answer

Comment: Gotcha, Tech Happily :)